# Getting current URL with JavaScript then using derived value in html code

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple question, but being a JavaScript newbie, I have no idea how to implement my findings.

I found a little snippit that uses JavaScript to pull in the current URL, and load that value to a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  }
</script>
```

so the value of `currentUrl` holds the current page's URL.

What I need to know is how to use that value within my page's HTML. The application I am attempting to use this for is the facebook comments plugin.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="**currentUrl**" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your `div` an id:

```
<div id="fb-comments" class="fb-comments"
```

Then you can set the `data-href` like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    document.getElementById("fb-comments").setAttribute("data-href", currentUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular question, I think:

```
// gets all elements of class-name 'fb-comments' from the document
var fbComments = document.getElementsByClassName('fb-comments');

// iterates through each of those elements
for (var i = 0, len = fbComments.length; i<len; i++) {
    // and sets the 'data-href' attribute to be the value held by the
    // the currentUrl variable
    fbComments[i].setAttribute('data-href', currentUrl);
}
```

For browsers that don't implement `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
// gets all div elements within the document
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

// iterates through each of those div elements, and
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i<len; i++) {
    // if the class attribute contains a string equal to 'fb-comments'
    if (divs[i].className.indexOf('fb-comments') !== -1) {
        // sets the 'data-href' attribute to be equal to the value held
        // by the currentUrl variable
        divs[i].setAttribute('data-href', currentUrl);
    }
}
```

References:

- [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute).

Comment: Should I leave the data-href="" portion blank then? The comments plugin is telling me "the plugin requires an href parameter."

Comment: This partiuclar JavaScript will simply set the attribute to whatever value is held in the variable. If a value's already there this will simply over-write it, so you can set it to a placeholder value if you want, typically `#`, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip David. My HTML editor was removing the field because I was leaving it blank. Inserted a "#", an voiala

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this -

```
<div id="myCommentBox" class="fb-comments" data-href="**currentUrl**" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>

var element = document.getElementById('myCommentBox');
element.setAttribute("data-href", currentUrl);
```

Notice that I gave the `<div>` an `id` attribute so that it would be easy to locate with `getElementById`. Remember that you'll need to call [`FB.XFBML.parse()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) once you change the `data-href` attribute in order to re-render the comment box.